# C# Form DropDownStyle different when called as class library from vbscript

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a windows form, that has a combo box. The combo box has property DropDownStyle. I have set its value to **DropDownList**. i.e. DropDownStyle: **DropDownList**. It works fine when the form is loaded as a windows application. But when I call it as class library from vbscript, it shows the the form with combo box having a different style (attached in screenshots). Can anyone suggest why is the difference occurring in its style?

EDIT: vbscript code is:

```
dim objTest, intResult, strResult
Set objTest = CreateObject ("Authentication.Initialize")
strResult = objTest.showOptions ("username", "Methods", "method1,method2")
Wscript.echo "Result = " & strResult
```

Form appears like this

[image: Form in design]

whereas form in design is:

[image]

Comment: could you show the code you use to bring up the form from VBScript? are you sure it is Simple? (ie., is the [text portion editable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle(v=vs.110).aspx))?

Comment: I have edited the post and included the vbscript. No it is not editable, oh so that means actually the style is not Simple, but it is appearing differently

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) and see if it helps to make the VBScript-hosted one look the same as your executable: your program may have visual styles enabled by default, whereas the VBScript host has not.

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

Make sure it is called before any control is rendered.

If you want your program to be "downgraded" to the old appearance, that is also possible, see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b8e994b4-b3d5-4043-9950-3656ae6ca686/disable-visual-styles?forum=winforms

```
 Application.VisualStyleState = VisualStyleState.NoneEnabled;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. I have called this in the constructor of the form before InitializeComponent() and it is appearing same now :)